# Items inside RecycleView wont align xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a `RecycleView` where i add items vertically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:paddingTop="5dp"
              android:paddingBottom="5dp"
              android:gravity="top">   

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/contrattiRecycle"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

and the itemcontainer is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"                
            android:id="@+id/ore"
            android:layout_weight="1"    
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/contratti"
            android:layout_weight="1"  
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/resa"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

When i fill the `RecycleView` with items they won't align properly but appear like the picture below:

[image]

The `RecycleView` is filled in a normal way. As long as every layout width is: `android:layout_width="match_parent"` it should expand this layouts to the parents width and the items logically should be aligned. Any suggestion?

Comment: Change all of the `<TextView>`'s `layout_width`s to `0dp`, and make sure you're passing the `ViewGroup` parameter to the `inflate()` call in `onCreateViewHolder()`. Also, the outer `<LinearLayout>` in the item layout seems unnecessary, unless you plan on adding something else in it later.

Comment: @MikeM. thank you very much dear sir. it did the trick, everything is aligned now. i'm using the outer LinearLayout cause i need to add an image later. but anyway thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> android:layout_weight="1"

as you use the `layout_weight` property,if you set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`,The system first assigns the three textviews their width wrap_content (wide enough to contain their content), and then assigns the remaining screen space to the three textviews according to the ratio of 1:1:1,so your content is not the same width, it will not appear aligned.

you just need to change **TextView**

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

in this case,it will divide the width by 1:1:1 first

Answer (score 1):

For both the linear layouts and text views make:

```
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:gravity="center"
```

not `center_vertical` or `center_horizontal`